# While loop is going to second function without exciting first function

Tags: node.js, sockets, while-loop

when I use this while loop function its going to the second function without executing the first function please help me out...

```
io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
  console.log("Connection With Socket Id "+ socket.id);
  
  socket.on('runTest', async data => {
    testCaseList = data;
    var i = 0;
    while(i<testCaseList.length && stopTestFlag == false){
      var id = testCaseList[i];
      var test  = await serverFunction.retrieveTestCaseData(id)  
      if(test.config.configType === 'Http'){
        httpConfig(test);
        console.log("Test is HTTP Type");
      }

      else if(test.config.configType === 'Udp'){
        udpConfig(test)
        console.log("Test is UDP Type");
      }
      i++;
    }
      socket.emit('runTest', 'Data Received From TestCase');
      socket.emit('status', 'Status Received From Complete TestCase');
      socket.emit('pass', testCasePass);
      socket.emit('failed', testCaseFail);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, maybe you can share the retrieveTestCaseData function code as well? Is that the function not being executed?

Comment: async function retrieveTestCaseData(id) {
var testCaseData;
var group;
var configuration;
await TestCase.findByPk(id)
.then(data => {
if (data) {testCaseData = data.dataValues;}
});
await TestGroup.findByPk(testCaseData.groupId).then(data=>{
if(data){group = data.dataValues;}
});
await Config.findByPk(group.configId).then(data=>{
if(data){
data.dataValues.configOption = JSON.parse(data.dataValues.configOption);
configuration=data.dataValues;
}
})
var returnObject={
testData:testCaseData,
config:configuration
} return returnObject;
}
module.exports={retrieveTestCaseData};

Comment: Hi, do not put relevant parts of  your question in comments; instead, edit the original one, giving us a chance to quickly understand the problem

Comment: I already put a Question ignore a comment please help us give me solution of this error